# Angular - how to make google maps show name from database after clicking on marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-ng-click

I created map using Google Map AngularJS Directive: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

I made it import coordinates from my database (over 200 records) like this:

```
<div id="map">
    <ng-map zoom="7" center="[52.00, 19.00]">
        <div ng-repeat="each in $ctrl.shops">
            <marker ng-repeat="shops in each" position="[{{shops.lat}}, {{shops.long}}]" />
        </div>
        <control name="shopMap" opened="true" />
    </ng-map>` 
</div>
```

The part of controller looks like:

```
userApi.getShops().then(function (response) {
        vm.shops = response.data;
    });
```

`getShops` is just a function from Api that gets data from the database.

It works fine, putting all the markers on the map. But the next step is to make the map display some info (shop.street, shop.city, shop.street) when clicking on marker. I tried to do it by `ng-click` but I have no idea how to correctly approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display some information [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) is commonly used in Google Maps:

> An InfoWindow displays content (usually text or images) in a popup
>   window above the map, at a given location. The info window has a
>   content area and a tapered stem. The tip of the stem is attached to a
>   specified location on the map.
>
> Typically you will attach an info window to a marker, but you can also
>   attach an info window to a specific latitude/longitude, as described
>   in the section on adding an info window below.

There is a `info-window` directive for initializing of info window in [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) library, the below example demonstrates how to display information once the marker is clicked

**Example**

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])

    .factory('userApi', function ($rootScope, $http) {
        var userApi = {
            getShops: function () {
                return $http.get('https://rawgit.com/vgrem/3962c1b67ec14fb734c4f7fccf697027/raw/data.json').then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        }
        return userApi;
    })

    .controller('mapController', function ($scope, NgMap, userApi) {

        NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
            $scope.map = map;
        });

        userApi.getShops().then(function (data) {
            $scope.shops = data;
        });

        $scope.showShop = function (event, shop) {
            $scope.selectedShop = shop;
            $scope.map.showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow', this);
        };

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapController">
    <ng-map default-style="true" zoom="5" center="59.339025, 18.065818">
        <info-window id="myInfoWindow">
            <div ng-non-bindable>
                <h4>{{selectedShop.name}}</h4>
            </div>
        </info-window>
        <marker ng-repeat="shop in shops"
                position="{{shop.pos}}" title="{{shop.name}}" id="{{shop.id}}" on-click="showShop(event, shop)">
        </marker>
    </ng-map>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation around the $compile service, typically you pass in some markup (stuff that can have directives in it) when that's passed as the argument to $compile it returns the combined link function for any directives in there.  Then on that link function you can pass in a scope object (existing scope or can create a new one with $rootScope.$new()).

Ends up looking something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('someThing', function($rootScope, $compile){
  return function(){
  
    var initialMarkup = "<button ng-click='clicked(shop)'>Click Me</button>";
    var someScope = $rootScope.$new();
    someScope.shop = "some shop details"
    someScope.clicked = function(shop){
      alert(shop);
    }
    var linkedElement = $compile(initialMarkup)(someScope);
    document.body.appendChild(linkedElement[0]);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div some-thing></div>
</div>
```

I've used this with Google maps before as well and you can apply the same to the InfoWindow contents but it did take some fiddling around the first time through.